# localhost:5500/em Username/Password error -------Oracle18c Express Edition

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

I followed a YouTube Video, and installed Oracle 18c Express Edition, gave password for localhost during installation. After successful installation I tried to access https://localhost:5500/em but couldn't login because of **username/password incorrect issue**. I tried usernames like: sys and sysdba but failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you did. You said "gave password for localhost during installation. ", but 'localhost' is not an account and so doesn't have a password.  'localhost', is a network name, used to indicate where network requests are to be routed.  Specifically, 'localhost' is the network name that equates to ip address 127.0.0.1, which is the local loopback address.

If you cannot remember the password you created for a database account, such as  SYS or SYSTEM, you can log on locally as SYSDBA and change what you need.  From a command prompt on the database server:

```
oracle:cdb$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Jul 1 09:23:37 2021
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> alter user sys identified by "halftrack";

User altered.

SQL>
```